# Implications of removing the index header line from patch

Tags: git, git-diff, git-patch

#### Context

I have a git repo ("parent repo") that contains a `.patch` file I have generated using `git diff --binary sometag` in another repository ("inner repo"). The parent repo is public and open for pull requests.
According to [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-generate-patch/en) this file contains a header line for each change that looks like this:

`index <hash>..<hash> <mode>`

This means every time two collaborators touch the same file (even in completely different lines) the resulting hash will be different and thus the index header will change causing a merge conflict that could be avoided.

I tried to remove these index headers and `git apply` still seems to work just fine.

#### Question

Are there any (hidden) implications that come with the removal of the index header lines?
Can it cause issues with binaries?

I assume the `git apply` tool will just look at the hashes for optimization reasons. I.e: "don't bother with a diff when you already have the resulting file".

I know the mode header is often embedded within the index header, it's ok for this information to be missing for my purposes.

Comment: "...causing a merge conflict that could be avoided." Are you observing this happening, or are you guessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any (hidden) implications that come with the removal of the index header lines?

They're not really *hidden*, they just don't reach out and whack you in the face (unlike, say, the way Git's index interacts with `.gitignore`).

> I assume the `git apply` tool will just look at the hashes for optimization reasons.

It's actually rather the reverse.  The apply command is given a diff, and tries to apply that diff to the existing file(s) in your working tree and/or index.  Those diffs have *context* as well as *changes* and it's possible that the context and/or changes don't match up with the existing file(s) to which the diff is to be applied.  If we're supposed to add:

```
(the BEST)
```

between line 12 and what was line 13, which should read

```
one ice cream flavor
is chocolate
```

but now they read:

```
the odors of skunks
and ferrets
```

well, perhaps that's not the BEST anymore, is it?

Anyway, if things look fishy, Git is capable of using the `index` line to poke around in your own local repository, to try to figure out what the file looked like *before* the diff got added.  If it can do so—if it can find the *original* file—it can then apply the patch *to* the original file.  It now has three files:

- the original file, found via the `index` line;
- the updated file, made by applying the patch *to* the original, which succeeds because the `index` line provides the actual original, so that the patch matches up; and
- your version of the file.

With these three versions of a single file, Git can now do a full-blown three-way merge, just as `git merge` would do, on that one file.  Git can figure out if the reason the patch didn't match up was because the lines moved—so now the patch can be applied to the *correct* lines, which might be line 52 and 53 instead of 12 and 13, for instance—or if it is because you made conflicting changes, and now there's a merge conflict.  (Perhaps you correctly identified these thiol compounds as worst-smelling things, although cadaverine and putrescine will [give them a run for the money](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/give-someone-a-good-run-for-their-money).)

> ... using `git diff --binary sometag` ...

A *binary* patch, from Git, requires that you have the correct preimage (the item given by the `index` line).  Without the index line, assuming I am reading [the source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2283e0e9af55689215afa39c03beb2315ce18e83/apply.c#L3130-L3153) correctly, Git will refuse to apply the patch, making the patch itself useless.  If you're going to delete the index line, you might as well delete the binary patch.